# Change session from picture to video record on holding button in camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using camera2 API for taking pictures and video recording. Both are working fine when I m using independently them.

But now I want to change the session from picture to video recording on holding the button for 1 seconds.

For that, I have a first close camera and then start video recording. But it is not working.

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to close camera. Just close current preview session then create a new one with `CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD` and add the `Surface` of `MediaRecorder` as new target.

See [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L637).

Or you can just use the current preview session and add target. But with `CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW` the quality of your video will be low, because high frame rate is given priority over the highest-quality post-processing.